# Slick carousel on load call the event

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Currently, code is working as expected on the event (after change) but I need to run the code which is inside the (after change) event.

As soon as the slick is initialized, I need to run the logic.

```js
$('.slick-wrapper').on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var $loginLogoutWideContainer = $('.row.hero-content'),
      $loginLogoutWideContainerHeight = $loginLogoutWideContainer.height(),
      $slideSelection = $(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)),
      $slideSelectionHeight = $slideSelection.height();

    if (($slideSelectionHeight < $loginLogoutWideContainerHeight) && ($(window).width() > 991)) {
      $slideSelection.height(($loginLogoutWideContainerHeight - 60) + 'px');
      $slickOffersWrapper.slick('resize');
    }
});

const slickSettings = {
    dots: true,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    mobileFirst: true,
    pauseOnDotsHover: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    customPaging: function(slider, i) { //Custom paging is to replace the dots with numbers
      var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data();
      return '<a>' + (i + 1) + '</a>';
    },
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1200,
      settings: {
        pauseOnDotsHover: false
      }
    }]
  };
  
  if ($('.slick-wrapper').children().length > 1) { //If slides are more than 1, construct slick
    $('.slick-wrapper').slick(slickSettings); // Construct Slick
  }
  
  function minHeightSlickDesktopSize() {
    var $loginLogoutWideContainerFixed = $('.row.hero-content');
    if (($(window).width() > 991)) {
      var $loginLogoutWideContainerFixedHeight = $loginLogoutWideContainerFixed.height();
      $('.offers-block-wide .slick-list').css({
        'min-height': ($loginLogoutWideContainerFixedHeight - 60) + 'px'
      });
    } else {
      $('.slick-list').css('min-height', 'auto');
      $('.slick-slide').css('height', 'auto');
    }
  };

  minHeightSlickDesktopSize();
  
  function assignHeightSlick() {

  // Assign the height of the wide container to the slick slides to match the height

  $('.slick-wrapper').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

    var $loginLogoutWideContainer = $('.row.hero-content'),
      $loginLogoutWideContainerHeight = $loginLogoutWideContainer.height(),
      $slideSelection = $(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)),
      $slideSelectionHeight = $slideSelection.height();

    if (($slideSelectionHeight < $loginLogoutWideContainerHeight) && ($(window).width() > 991)) {
      $slideSelection.height(($loginLogoutWideContainerHeight) + 'px');
      $slickOffersWrapper.slick('resize');
    }

  });
}
assignHeightSlick();
```

```css
.row.hero-content {
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>

<div class="parent">

  <div class="row hero-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

  <div class="slick-wrapper">
    <div class="one">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    <div class="two">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages</div>
    <div class="three">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I need to call 'if' condition as soon as the slick carousel is built. It should capture the first slide and apply this logic. My logic is working once it comes back to the first slide.

I tried to init (.on(init)) but not working.

Comment: It may help to [show](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you initialize the slider and configure the "init" handler.

Comment: @showdev: Changed the code. I want to know if what I'm calling inside the init function is correct.